# Youtube API List channels other than Google

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I am sitting hours and cannot find the answer for issue I have. I am using latest Youtube API for .NET

The problem I wanna solve is to take information - mostly id from any channel for Youtube channel I give the name.

```
var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApiKey = "key",
                ApplicationName = "appName"
            });

var asd = youtubeService.Channels.List(new Repeatable<string>(new List<string> { "snippet,contentDetails,statistics" }));

asd.ForUsername = "Mauzer";

var dsa = await asd.ExecuteAsync();
```

To achieve that I am using `ForUsername` property. However the result of call does not always return the result.

For example if I type "Google" as Username it return the Google`s channel. However it doesn't work for all channels I can find exploring Youtube.

Anyone is familiar and know what I am missing?

Comment: Issue the following search term `user:8327971 forusername` in SO's search box; you'll get quite a few recent answers I gave relative to this issue (cannot repeat that info here once more since that would go against SO guidelines).

Comment: **Channel** - two "n", one "l" ....